# Cannot create NX workspace although it says it has successfully created workspace

Tags: node.js, angular, nx-angular

Cannot see the created NX workspace although it says it has successfully created workspace. 
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Node v16.17.0.  
Here's my terminal output:

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest MyORG
✔ What to create in the new workspace · angular
✔ Application name                    · MeanEComm
✔ Default stylesheet format           · scss
✔ Set up distributed caching using Nx Cloud (It's free and doesn't require registration.) · No


 >  NX   Nx is creating your v14.5.10 workspace.

   To make sure the command works reliably in all environments, and that the preset is applied correctly,
   Nx will run "npm install" several times. Please wait.

✔ Installing dependencies with npm
✔ Nx has successfully created the workspace.

 ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————


 >  NX   Nx CLI is not installed globally.

   This means that you might have to use "yarn nx" or "npx nx" to execute commands in the workspace.
   Run "yarn global add nx" or "npm install -g nx" to be able to execute command directly.


 ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————


 >  NX   First time using Nx? Check out this interactive Nx tutorial.

   https://nx.dev/angular-tutorial/01-create-application
   
   Prefer watching videos? Check out this free Nx course on YouTube.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mYLe9Kp9VM&list=PLakNactNC1dH38AfqmwabvOszDmKriGco
```

Comment: is the folder `MyOrg` within your working directory?

Comment: @LaurenceIninda Yes, it is